# Scope not updating when values changed from iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-scope

Im have an image picker that is contained within an iframe. The image picker updates an input field with an ng-model value {{ post.image }} like so:

```
<input required type="text" id="image" name="image" placeholder="Competition image" ng-model="post.image"/>
```

The input field is updated from within the iframe like so:

```
$('#image', window.parent.document).val(img);
```

The value of the input does change however the scope value does not.

I've tried using $watch but this only seems to work on actual keypress change

Answer (score 1):

Since you're updating the value of the input field directly via a third party library, no events are fired and angular is unaware the value has changed.

You'll need to explicitly fire a change event on the element.

```
$('#image', window.parent.document).trigger('change');
```

A cleaner approach may be to have a function that updates the scope directly, rather than the input field. Since the event is triggered by something outside your controller, the easiest way to do this is probably to fire an event on the root scope.

Unfortunately doing this across an iframe is probably more pain than it's worth. If you wanted to give it a try, you'd need to do something like this.

```
$rootScope = angular.element(window.parent.document).injector().get('$rootScope')

$rootScope.$broadcast('setImage', value);
```

And then within your controller

```
$scope.$on('setImage', function(event, value){
    $scope.post.image = value;
});
```